# node.js - How to divide a variable by numbers in array

Tags: node.js, arrays

This may be a dumb question, but I just started learning, so... Wrote this code to find prime numbers, however it gets lost with a few numbers higher than 100, like 121 and 299, for example. The thing is they are divisible by some prime numbers (11 and 13 for example) that were already added to the array.

```
var primeNum = [2, 3, 5, 7];

for (var i = 7; i < 1000; i++){
    if ((i % 2 !== 0) && (i % 3 !== 0) && (i % 5 !== 0) && (i % 7 !==0)){
        primeNum.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(primeNum);
```

Is therer a way to substitute the conditions on the if statement to make it divide the variable by the items on the array?

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the sieve of eratosthenes is what you are looking for.
Here is a quick and dirty implementation.

```
function sieve(n) {
    let numbers = {};

    // We mark all numbers as prime
    for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = true;
    }

    //we just need to do this algorithm for numbers, that are greater or equal the sqrt of the given number
    let finalIndex = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));

    for(let i=2; i <= finalIndex; i++) {
        //if our number is marked as prime
        if(numbers[i]){
            //mark every other number, that can be divided by this number as false
            for(let j=2*i; j<=n; j+=i){
                numbers[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //return the numbers marked as prime
    let result = [];
    for(let k in numbers) {
        if(numbers[k]){
            result.push(k);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(sieve(1000));
```

Comment: That's sick, but I'm a simple guy, haha. I was expecting more a yes or no answer and, if yes, what would it be, or what I am doing wrong. Taking baby steps here, but appreciate your answer  :)